Cannot find name 'TokenSet authjs
I am working with AuthJs v5 to get access token through our server, yet I found an issue with the authjs importing types. I could not get the tokenSet from the library or find the types related NPM package.
import Credentials from "next-auth/providers/credentials"
import NextAuth, { NextAuthConfig } from "next-auth"

export const options: NextAuthConfig = {
    providers: [
        Credentials({
            // You can specify which fields should be submitted, by adding keys to the `credentials` object.
            // e.g. domain, username, password, 2FA token, etc.
            credentials: {
                email: { label: "Email", type: "text", placeholder: "test@test.com" },
                password: { label: "Password", type: "password" }
            },

            authorize: async (credentials, request) => {
            //    get the token logic
            },
        }),
    ],
    callbacks: {
        async jwt({ user, account, token }) {
                    // Get the token logic
                    const tokens: TokenSet = {token:"test"};
            }
        },
        
    },
};



Looking into the documentation I found that they have a core package with the types which solved my issue here is the solution:
pnpm add @auth/core

In the code I needed to add the next line:
import { TokenSet } from "@auth/core/types"

